# Move a specfic CSV file prefixed by a word(TCE*) from blob to SQL table

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

i would like to know how do we copy a specfic patter named files (prefixed by tce)from bob to SQL tabel.

if its a single file im able to load it,but i would like to all the files tht starts with tce.

Comment: What version of ADF are you using? You can do this via ADF expressions natively via UI or JSON. You can also do this via SSIS using expressions. This is commonly known as a dynamic file connection manager.

Comment: hi,does my answer helps you?

Answer (score 1):

You could set wildcard in blob source dataset when you set your copy activity.

Firstly,follow the [statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-azure-blob-storage#dataset-properties) in blob storage connector, don't set fileName in blob storage dataset setting:

[image]

Then set the wildcard in copy activity source.

[image]